# Is there a syntax to resolve ambiguity in CSS class names between two style sheets?

Tags: css, stylesheet

Let's say I have an HTML page that imports two style sheets like so:

```
<link href="Styles1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Styles2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Also assume that a class with the same name appears in both of the above style sheets.

```
.SomeStyle {font-weight:bold;  } /* in Styles1.css */
.SomeStyle {font-weight:normal;} /* in Styles2.css */
```

**Question**: Is there a syntax where I can apply the class to an element in a way that disambiguates which version of the style to use?

For example (pseudo-code):

```
<span id="mySpan" class="Styles1.css:SomeStyle">Example</span>
```

*Disclaimer:* I know that a better solution would be to resolve name conflict between the two style sheets,  but I am asking mostly for academic reasons.

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do on the HTML side. With your specific example, obviously the last declaration will be applied, and there's nothing you can do about it without changing some CSS.

Comment: I believe it works just like if you put the same class-name twice in a single document. The second declaration will override the first. So in your example above you'd end up with normal font-weight no matter what. I don't think there's a way to override it.

Comment: So it sounds like it might be a good idea to reference the external style sheet that you'd consider most specific last just in case there are any future conflicts. Especially on a site where multiple sheets are used and someone could come along later and accidentally create a duplicate class name because they weren't using the two style sheets together in whatever page they were working on.

Comment: that sounds like a good idea, yeah. And always trying to be specific enough so as not to collide with anything else... which however can be *hard* in practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a syntax where I can apply the class to an element in a way that disambiguates which version of the style to use?

No. The latter style overrides the former into one computed style. There is no way to undo that.

The only thing you could do is attach additional classes to each definition:

```
.SomeStyle.First {font-weight:bold;  } /* in Styles1.css */
.SomeStyle.Second {font-weight:normal;} /* in Styles2.css */
```

and then use

```
<span id="mySpan" class="SomeStyle Second">Example</span>
```

Comment: The latter meaning the stylesheet that was referenced last in the HTML? Is that up to the browser implementation or is that part of the HTML/CSS specification?

Comment: @JohnFx no, the latter references two classes (the rule will only work if both classes are applied to an element at the same time). It's not what you are looking for but it's the thing that comes closest

Comment: @JohnFx: That's CSS specificity.

Comment: Can you clarify what "The Latter references two classes" means exactly?

Comment: @John `.SomeStyle.First {}` declares a rule that applies only when two classes are set: "SomeStyle" and "First". Whenever you give an element those two classes at the same time, the rule will come into effect. You would have to rework your markup to implement this, though. If you can't change the markup, nothing will work to get hold of the first rule except for removing the second style sheet from the document. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Some people choose to add classes to the body tag of one more the pages so that they can disambiguate eg.

```
<body class="newer">
```

then use this when specifying newer functionality

```
.SomeStyle {font-weight:bold;} /* in Styles1.css */
.newer .SomeStyle {font-weight:normal;} /* in Styles2.css */
```

This can start to get messy though. It may be best to have your global styles on one or more files, and then page specific styles in a subsequent file. If you need to change this back, add a third rule to the page specific file and set the style back:

```
.SomeStyle {font-weight:bold;} /* in Styles1.css */
.SomeStyle {font-weight:normal;} /* in Styles2.css */
.SomeStyle {font-weight:bold;} /* in PageSpecific.css */
```

Answer (score 0):

There may possibly be a way to use jQuery or something similar to rename (remove and add as a different name) one of the classes so that it has a unique name. Maybe you could read both stylesheets rather than linking and have jQuery go through, add the classes to the page as it reads them and then change any class names that already exist?

I'm not an expert in jQuery by any means, but from my limited use, I'd suspect it could be done. The question comes then in how do you use the 2nd class since you'd have to know what it'll be named and all that...

Just a quick thought...

Comment: Not looking for a workaround. Just wanted to know if the CSS/HTML syntax supported this type of namespace resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, not a very detailed one but. Maybe you can use php include, and have a submit button to call the function via JavaScript to include he required css. (in-fact you wouldn't need JS)