# Guidelines for class naming when building a framework/tool

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a small tool with JavaScript that generates a lot of HTML & CSS & I am planning to ship a stylesheet with the JavaScript so it all renders correctly. I am trying to make sure I do not run in obvious [stylesheet collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010074/is-there-a-syntax-to-resolve-ambiguity-in-css-class-names-between-two-style-shee), so I am looking for guidelines, best practices etc... for the naming of classes that will be used in a framework/tool.

What do you use that works well for naming to avoid collisions?

Comment: I would suggest to use a prefix on every class / ids you use. Something obvious like the name of your tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating the HTML too why not add a distinctive class or id to the container and then your CSS can simply style up only those elements *within* your container.

HTML:

```
<div class="myWierdAndWonderfulGeneratedThing">
<p><label>foo<label><span>bar</span></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myWierdAndWonderfulGeneratedThing label { color: red; }
.myWierdAndWonderfulGeneratedThing span { color: blue; }
```

You might also use JavaScript to generate unique ids for your wrappers and corresponding style rules.

HTML:

```
<div id="myWierdAndWonderfulGeneratedThing_0001">
 ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myWierdAndWonderfulGeneratedThing_0001 label { color: green; }
```